# How to get access to the object bound to node in DevExpress XtraTreeList?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, devexpress, xtratreelist

I have created an XtraTreeList control that is bound to my bindingSource and it uses a list of custom objects. The MultiSelect property is set to true, so when the user selects multiple nodes I want to define what objects are bound to them. But unfortunately I haven't found any property related to contained data (except the Data which is obsolete and is always null). I also tried to use TreeListNode.GetValue, but it only gives me a displayed value and not the object itself

Is there a way to get access to the object bound to node in XtraTreeList?

The last resort is to use Unbound mode and to create them manually, but I would like to know if there is a simple solution for that

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the TreeList.[GetDataRecordByNode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_GetDataRecordByNodetopic) method for this purpose.